# Windows 8/8.1 UEFI Secure Boot custom keys

Tags: windows-8, boot, security, uefi

Is there the ability to run the OS Windows 8/8.1 with custom keys? I created my certificate with "makekert" utility, then i use signtool to sign files "memtest.efi", "bootmgfw.efi", "bootmg.efi", "winload.efi". OS is loaded successfully. But when the Secure Boot turn on, immediately falls with error "0xc0000428". If i sign Ubuntu with these keys with Secure Boot mode on, Ubuntu is starting well.
Windows don't write on which filename boot fail.

Answer (score 0):

You have to sign all system files loaded - boot files, winload, kernel, drivers also system dll's.

Have you replaced X.509 certificate in firmware ?

Comment: Yes, i replace certificate in firmware. But i don't know which system files i need to sign.